# How to disable this suggestion when using tab key? (VScode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode(1.30.2).
I just need pure Html snippets, but this VScode pop-up suggestion makes me annoyed.
Please check the image below..

[image: vscode image]

I just want Html snippets only, but as you can see, wrong suggestion appears.
(ex: [abc]page )

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // Controls whether completions should be computed based on words in
>   the document.

```
 "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```

`true` is the default for that setting - change it to `false` in your settings.json.

Also, you will find these two settings helpful - to put the emmet abbreviations at the top of the suggestion list:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",

"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
```

Comment: Thank you :D...my problem has been completely resolved!